# OpenCV: What is the correlation between camera calibration and depth map computing?

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, 3d-reconstruction

I followed the opencv tutorials called 'Camera calibration and 3d reconstruction' (https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_table_of_contents_calib3d/py_table_of_contents_calib3d.html) and I do not understand what is the correlation between camera calibration and creating a depth map. I can see that focal length is in the equation for disparity, but according to code there's no need to compute the camera matrix 'cause its not used anywhere.
Am I right or someone can point me my mistake?
All code is in the opencv link.
I'm using python.

Comment: The examples use undistorted images as input. If you're using a real camera, you need to undistort the images before using them.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot.